# Conduction of AC current and Flux linkage in the conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

why flux linkage is more in center than outer of a conductor when an alternating current is flowing through it ? Is this the reason why more back EMF(voltage) is produced in the center than back EMF produced at the outer? Can anyone please explain the phenomenon ?

Answer (score 0):

Flux linkage is more for AC due to its property of alternating direction of current. So change in magnetic field can be called periodic and changing for each time interval (assuming Sinusoidal current).
Secondly, back emf is only generated in case of inductance which is there due to  generally a pair of twisted wires going.